# Netbeans and Zend Framework 2 configuration - zh.sh file

Tags: php, netbeans-7, zend-framework2

I am new to PHP and Zend Framework 2.

I am currently going through the [ZF2 tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html). I've run the commands:

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

Then opened up the latest Netbeans version. However, when asked for the `zh.sh` file, I couldn't find it anywhere in the `zf2-tutorial` folder. Is this file something that we need to create or is it expected to exist by default in the ZF2?

It'd be great if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: I thought nebeans currently only supported ZF 1 thought I may be wrong as i've not had a chance to look into ZF2 yet!

Comment: ZF2 does not have the same command line tools as ZF1 had. It is in the works but has not been release. NetBeans has also not issue an update to support ZF2. Right now the Zend Framework section is for ZF1.

Answer (score 3):

As other have hinted, NetBeans has not caught up to ZF2 yet (ZF has only been out for a handful of weeks).

As of right now, ZF2 has no command-line tooling (ie: zf.sh).  Instead, you're encouraged to use the Skeleton Application to get things started.

While NetBeans doesn't have any specific ZF2 support, it's still a great IDE to use while developing ZF2 projects.

Just skip the ZF-specific stuff.  Grab the Skeleton App, and create a new NetBeans project ("from existing sources"), and start hacking.

In all honesty, I can't remember ever using any of the ZF-specific stuff in netbeans.  The framework is just a bunch of PHP files, and NetBeans works well without any framework-specific knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know the content of zf.sh, but I was using this zf.bat in windows as it should be zf.sh in linux so's. This way I got from netbeans my zend core in the creation project phase ( with no errors):

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

*With Zend included in php.ini, and `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=5000` set in the same file (also set `max_execution_time=5000`). This is because it didn't work for me to put it in command line orders.*